# Woocommerce Taxes doesn't show in cart

Tags: woocommerce, cart

In woocommerce I've set a country code specific tax. This seems to work, but the problem is that it doesn't show at the Cart Totals in the Cart. VAT stays at €0,00 but when clicked on Proceed to Checkout, it does show the correct VAT.

The prices are set exclusive of tax. The tax rates are only based on the country code.

What could be the problem?

I am using version version 2.1.7
These are my settings:

- Enable Taxes: yes
- Prices Entered With Tax:  No, I will enter prices exclusive of tax
- Calculate Tax Based On: customer billing address
- Default customer address: no address
- Shipping tax class: shipping tax class based on cart items
- Rounding: off
- Additional Tax Classes: Reduced Rate, Zero Rate
- Display prices in the shop: excluding tax
- Price display suffix: empty
- Display prices during cart/checkout: excluding tax
- Display tax totals: as a single total

Comment: It would be helpful to see your tax settings. Something was probably entered wrong. Also what version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: I am using version version 2.1.7. I have figured that my settings are fine, but that woocommerce is programmed to not show the tax in the cart totals before pressing on checkout, because after pressing on checkout, the user has the ability to change the shipping or billing country. So the tax only gets calculated after the user has set the country. I would like to know if there is a way to show it also in the cart totals. Any idea?

Comment: This would be pretty complex. You'd have to programmatically set the country, state, zip, city, etc. and invoke the tax calculation method.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not **that** complex. I just did that a few days ago. I also thought that it would be a lot of code, but actually its 2 filters for taxes, and 1 filter for shipping (if you also want that pre-calculated).

Please read my self-answer on this page: [How to show correct tax on basket (BEFORE checkout)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527102/how-to-show-correct-tax-on-basket-before-checkout)